# AWS lambda does not have a handler definition window anymore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS have changed their Lambda function definition interface, and i cannot find a way to change an entry point (handler function) anymore. Any ideas how to do it now?

Here is what i have when i add a new function:

[image]

Previously it looked like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is in `Basic settings`:

[image]

[image]